# Generate Scripts for entire database - why SQL Server try to create views first

Tags: sql-server, code-generation

I am using SQL Server 2019 developer version - 15.0.2000.5.
I used `Generate Scripts` for entire database - just checked all and generated scripts.  But upon running file I noticed errors at beginning and everything worked except for views.  It seems that SQL Server added creating scripts for views at the beginning of file.  Is there a way I could re-arrange this or is this a bug?  What I did to fix was just re-run only view scripts - but it just seems like Microsoft should know better.

SQL Server 2016 express does same thing also?